# React Chrome Extension with Multiple scripts

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension, build

I know with react, it puts everything together into one js file usually called main.

Is it possible to change the config of build on react to keep some files separate in order to maintain chromes **"content_script"**, **"background"**, and **"popup"** intact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a react problem but rather a bundler issue. If you are using webpack, you need to have multiple [entry points](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/entry-points/).

e.g.

```
entry: {
    popup: path.join('src', 'popup', 'index.js'),
    background: path.join('src', 'background', 'index.js'),
    content: path.join('src', 'content', 'index.js'),
},
```

inside your webpack.config.js.

If you are interested in boilerplate that provides this functionality, you can look at https://github.com/AnilRedshift/chrome-extension-webpack-boilerplate